# Replace the alphabetical characters of a column with numbers

Tags: bash, shell, awk

How can I replace the alphabetical characters of a column with numbers? I have a file such as:

```
1  A 005
2  A 007
3  A 009
4  C 005
5  C 007
6  C 009
7  P 005
8  P 007
9  P 009 
10 S 010
11 S 010
12 T 020
```

I want to replace the column two with numbers so that all **A**s are replaced with 1; all **C**s are replaced with 2 and all **P**s are replaced with 3; and the next character with the next number. The desired output is:

```
1  1 005
2  1 007
3  1 009
4  2 005
5  2 007
6  2 009
7  3 005
8  3 007
9  3 009 
10 4 010
11 4 010
12 5 020
```

Comment: What output do you want when a previous letter occurs, like `10 A 010` ?

Comment: I guess you mean "letters"?

Comment: @Walter A, If it occurs, it should be replaced with the same number.

Answer (score 2):

***Solution 1st:*** In case your Input_file is same as shown sample(sorted by 2nd column) you could try following `awk` too on same.

```
awk 'prev!=$2{count++} {prev=$2;$2=count;print}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case your Input_file is NOT sorted then I am sorting it first and then using above solution 1st `awk` command to get the output.

```
sort -k2 Input_file | awk 'prev!=$2{count++} {prev=$2;$2=count;print}'
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13
In this case, it is sorted but there are cases when the letters appear in later rows. In that case, 2nd solution works.

Comment: Does awk '!seen[$2]++{c++} {$2=c} 1'  work same as your 1st solution?

Comment: @user3132983, from looking vice it should work same but haven't tested it, why don't you give it a try and let us all know then :)

Comment: I tested it with one of my files, it works as your solution. I don't have much expertise with awk thus I wanted to make sure this solution is fundamentally correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!num[$2]{num[$2]=++c} {$2=num[$2]}1' file
```

- the first `condition{action}` means: if second field is a newcomer, store an auto-increment integer value for that letter key. For your example `num['A']=1`, and so on. Note that variable `c` which is not initialized, 
  starts from zero, that means `++c` will be firstly `1`, then `2` and so on.
- The second `{action}` means: replace second field with the value from the previous associative array using that field as the key.
- final `1` means the default action, to print the line, same as `print` or `print $0`